# Open Visual Studio command prompt from C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open Visual studio Command prompt using C# code.

Here is my code

```
private void Execute(string vsEnvVar)
{

 var vsInstallPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(vsEnvVar);

 // vsEnvVar can be VS100COMNTOOLS, VS120COMNTOOLS, VS140COMNTOOLS

 if (Directory.Exists(vsInstallPath))
 {
    var filePath = vsInstallPath + "vsvars32.bat";
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        //start vs command process
        Process proc = new Process();

        var command = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec");
        command = @"" + command + @"";

        var batfile = @"E:\Test\vstest.bat";
        var args = string.Format("/K  \"{0}\" \"{1}\"" ,filePath, batfile);  

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  

        proc.Start();
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("File Does not exists " + filePath);
     }
 }
}
```

But the args string is not getting properly formatted.
I am getting below formatted string

```
"/K  \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools\\vsvars32.bat\" \"E:\\Test\\vstest.bat\""
```

extra "\" is getting added.

Please point out what I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: What is the end result of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MaYaN, I have to run msbuild on solution file, Solution file can be created using vs 10, 12 or 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is being formatted as you asked, but you have asked for the wrong thing. `"E:\Test\VStest.bat"` is being passed as an argument to `VCVars.bat`, but I suspect you want it to be executed after it.

Try this:

```
var args = string.Format("/S/K \" \"{0}\" && \"{1}\" \"" ,filePath, batFile);
```

This should produce:

```
"/S/K \" \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools\\vsvars32.bat\" && \"E:\\Test\\vstest.bat\" \" \"
```

Which as a string is:

```
/S/K " "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" && "E:\Test\vstest.bat" "
```

Comment: thanks for reply, Now able to open visual studio command prompt. But some invalid characters are getting appended in the command   F:\Program\Debug >∩╗┐cd /D E:/Temp/Prog.   </br> My first command in bat file is change directory to some project solution (.sln) path. But "∩╗┐" is getting appendind in the command.  </br>  I am using args as <br> var args = string.Format("/K \" \"{0}\" && \"{1}\" \"", filePath, batfile);

Comment: Got it working, changed the Encoding of batfile to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: `CMD.exe`, the windows command prompt, does not understand UTF-8 by default, you might try `chcp 65001` to set the codepage to utf8 (I haven't tested this)

Comment: Also you really need the `/S` argument here.